# What is the best way to save data in a medium sized database?

Tags: database, perl, bash, csv, text

I would like to save some data in a structured way to use it later on. Right now, I have different bash/perl scripts to extract a lot of data and format it in numerous different text files. I am automating all of that. Now I have a list of observations (environment, like rain, hail..) with some variables in lines (each line is an observation). I can extract this all right with bash, but with the time and zome (Lat/Long) I need to check other variables, 800 per observation. I wonder how can I store the thounsands of observations (or more) with those 800 variables (names, values) to use it later on. I'm wondering if I should find something else then .txt files.

On top of it, all the 800 variables are in fact a repetition of the same variables (same name) at different times (00, 03, 06, ..., 48). Also, for some reason, a couple of variables have the same name with different values at the same time (this is not *my* data).

Right now, I can read each line of my observations and see each variable. Now I need to place 1 observation with 1 stack of variables (the 800), and do this for every line.

Would you have an idea for me on the format to use (the less programs/extensions/etc is the best) to store this? I see .csv files, or .txt files, but I can't seem to figure a simple way to classify all of this (and how to do it).

I've wrote something like this;

```
while IFS=' ' read -r year month date lat long #And other variables to read line.
do
   ./MyExtractionScript.ksh $lat $long #I need lat/long for position.
done < "$File"
```

Right now my *MyExtractionScript.ksh* saves all to `${fileout}` in a format where each line is a variable in a file in *TMPDIR*, like this;

```
BS    8500    0    7.5339
RE       0    0    5.9412
UU   12000    3    6.0882
VV   12000    3  -11.0595
```

The "0" that becomes "3" is the hour (0 to 48), and the "VV" are the names.

Should I do observations objects in csv, with time objects inside for each hour? How? :(

I'm sorry my question is long and far from precise, short or concise. I am not, by all means, an expert. Please help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance. Have a great day.

PS: Sorry for my english, I am a french canadian from Montréal.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "to use it later on"? The best way to store the data, depends hugely on what requirements you have as you extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file. That is a comma separated values file. The robust, and probably easiest way is to [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) in Perl. This is what a CSV file should look like, I believe it's self explanatory and a simple format:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

What you want is this:

```
# Write array of arrays as csv file
csv (in => $aoa, out => "file.csv", sep_char=> ";");
```

Then to open it later:

```
my $aoa = csv (in => "data.csv");
```

Then to retrieve the data to either edit or review:

```
my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {
    $row->[2] =~ m/pattern/ or next; # 3rd field should match
    push @rows, $row;
    }
close $fh;

$csv->eol ("\r\n");
open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "new.csv" or die "new.csv: $!";
$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
```

The synopsis it provides should be suitable for your needs unless you want a real database with [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a really good answer, detailed and precise. I will do exactly that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I'd simply recommend using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).